# How do I expand all columns in Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with many columns. The columns are all a small standard width. Double-clicking the partition line between columns will expand the column width to encompass the longest string in that column.

Is there a shortcut to perform this operation on every column in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Just a comment: "howto" as one word usually means "this is a guide" not "how do I".

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Click where the row and column headers meet, this will select the entire sheet, like so:

[image]

**Then** double-click any one of the column partition lines.

I do this all the time, and it's as quick as you can get.

Comment: Cool trick You rock!

Comment: excel black magic 101 lol...

Answer (score 26):

I don't know about shortcut. I use menu.
1) Select The Full Spreadsheet
2) Select Format
3) Column
4) Autofit Selection

Comment: +1 I like this solution because it works on whatever range you select and you can exclude, for instance, titles that you want to span many columns.

Comment: Sometimes for long strings the autofit does not expand to fit the longest line in that column. navigating this tip brought me to the other options of manually setting the width which was useful.

Comment: And for particularly long strings there are times when Excel just fails. Although, I haven't run into this yet with the newer versions.

Comment: Could you update this for 2010 please? Or at least specify the version you are explaining this for.

Comment: At the time of this post I believe I was using a 2000 version of office at home and 2003 at work.

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all cells, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Is that working in all excel versions?

Comment: @boboes works for 2010

Answer (score 6):

Try selecting everything (CTRL + A twice rapidly, or just select the columns you want), and then double-click a partition line.  In Excel 2007, that solution seems to work just fine; in other words, it automatically sizes each column to its own longest string.

Comment: doesn't work in 2003

Comment: It does work in 2003.  In both versions, you have to make sure the whole column is selected, not just a range of cells.

Comment: Why CTRL+a *twice*? Was that really needed in some version of Excel?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: For example in Excel 2013, pressing Ctrl+A _once_ selects the current block of cells, which have contents in them -- equivalent to Ctrl+Shift+Space. The following _second_ Ctrl+A selects the entire sheet.

Answer (score 1):

[image]in Excel 2016 you can select all with Ctrl + A then on Home tab look for Format menu. Click and select Autofit Column Width

Answer (score -1):

Select All - "Control" A

Expand all column width and heights "Alt" H-O-I

Comment: there are no dashes when you expand column width and heights- "Alt" HOI