# Is there a shortcut in excel that will expand the column width to show the entire column header

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, headers

Is there a shortcut in excel that will expand all the column width(s) to show the entire column header as well as complete column data?

Now I need to go to each and every column in the excel sheet and double click on the border between every column and expand it
completely to increase the column width to show the complete text in that column. I want to get this done in one click per excel worksheet

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Click on the top left corner of the spreadsheet *(left of A, and above 1)*
With the entire spreadsheet selected, double click on one of the borders, and it will do it to every row or column *(depending on if you clicked between rows or columns)*

Comment: How do I click "one of the borders?" I'm trying to click the border of the column and row, the border of the top left corner, the border of a random cell, but it's not working.

Never mind. I found an image explanation in this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/161395/495155

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> - To Select All
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> - To AutoFit collum width

Comment: Excel 2003: ALT + O + C + A

Comment: Excel 2007 & 2010: ALT + H + O + I

Comment: @Eden Just to make sure people are aware, this also works on office 365.

Answer (score 6):

In Excel 2007, on the Home ribbon, to the right there is a Icon that says Format. Click that to get the drop down. There is AutoFit Column Width and Row Height.

Click the triangle in the upper left of the speadsheet to select the whole sheet. Then use AutoFit.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd> while on a cell on the column you want to do the auto-fit thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Step by step instructions:**

- Expand the selection to the current region (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>)
- Type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to select the Home tab on the Excel ribbon
- Type <kbd>O</kbd> to select the Format menu in the Cells sub-area
- Type <kbd>I</kbd> to select “autofit column width”